# how to reference database item attachments in couchapp

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I'm learning couchapp and it looks pretty easy to query database items.

But I have items with attachments, and I'd like to add hyperlinks to the attachments:

```
 <a href="/databasename/{{id}}/{{attachment}}">{{description}}</a>
```

I can get `id`, `attachment` and `description` setup properly, but how do I get the current database name (or URL) from within a couchapp javascript function?

Comment: Put it on a variable or use relative paths.

Comment: how do you put it on a variable? where do you get it from?

Comment: It depends from your application... for example, you can get it by parsing the pathname in [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location). Or, as I said: use relative urls.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use relative urls, you can fetch the db name in following way:

```
var dbname = unescape(document.location.href).split('/')[2]
```

since your href looks like: `http://host:port/dbname/doc...`

This is also the code jquery.couch.app.js uses. So if you are using it, it's available for you in initialization code:

```
$.couch.app(function(app) { alert(app.db.name); });
```

Comment: cool, i'll give that a shot (maybe store it in a state variable or something for functions that don't have `app` as an input parameter)